# How to use Numerator when a very large expression is not in normal form

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to extract the numerator of a very large term that is not in normal form e.g. it is a sum of rational polynomials:

```
expr = poly1/poly2 + poly3/poly4 + ... + polyn/polym;
```

If I take `Numerator[expr]` it doesn't work as it only accepts `expr=poly1/poly2`, i.e. in normal form. If I run `Numerator[Together[expr]]` or `Numerator[Factor[expr]]` I get what I'm after, however if `expr` has many terms (e.g. tens of thousands), it takes a very long time. If I do the equivalent function in Maple: `numer(expr)`, it does the same thing as `Numerator[Together[expr]]` but in a fraction of the time. I am working with very large sums of rational polynomials so is there a faster/better way to do this? In other words is there a faster way to manipulate `expr` so `Numerator` gives the desired result? Thanks

Comment: it always helps, if you want fast answers, to give a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
expr = x/(x + a) + y/(x + b)^2 + p/q

(*   p/q + x/(a + x) + y/(b + x)^2   *)
```

If you apply `Together` you get the following:

```
Together[expr]

(*  (a b^2 p + 2 a b p x + b^2 p x + b^2 q x + a p x^2 + 2 b p x^2 + 
 2 b q x^2 + p x^3 + q x^3 + a q y + q x y)/(q (a + x) (b + x)^2)  *)
```

It is easier to look at the image, rather than at the Mma expression:

[image]

Then

```
Numerator[Together[expr]]
```

gives you the desired answer:

```
(*  a b^2 p + 2 a b p x + b^2 p x + b^2 q x + a p x^2 + 2 b p x^2 + 
 2 b q x^2 + p x^3 + q x^3 + a q y + q x y  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: The OP explicitly states a desire to avoid `Numerator[Together[expr]]`.

Comment: Yep this works but the problem I'm facing is that when the expression is extremely large, `Numerator[Together[expr]]` takes about 10x longer to run than the equivalent maple function. Is there another way to manipulate `expr` such that `Numerator` will return the correct result?

Comment: If there was another way, `Together` would use it. Without seeing the expression it is difficult to guess why `Together` is slow. What version of Mathematica is involved here? I ask because it is possible that a change in the internal heuristics for choosing a GCD method might have made matters better or worse.

Comment: The expression is over 10,000 terms long so it's hard to show what it looks like. I'm using version 11.2.0.0. I actually need to solve for the coefficients of the polynomials that make the numerator zero (in hindsight that might have been a better question to ask) so maybe there is another way to do this that avoids `Together`.